# Python: Memory allocation error

Tags: python, memory, segmentation-fault, allocation

I am reading rows from a sqlite db, looping over them and then using the variables from each row as arguments for a function which generates plots, 
something like the following pseudo code

```
conn=sqlite3.connect(db)
c=conn.cursor()
myrows=c.execute("select * from values WHERE var=1")
for burst in myrows:
    met=burst[1]
    make_plot(met)
c.close()
```

After a certain amount of time this gives either one of the following errors:

1) 86392 items requested but only 0 read Segmentation fault

2) unable to alloc 3072000 bytes
   Aborted

3) Segmentation fault

The make_plot() has to read in a large file (~8 mB) and do some operations on the data, and there are ~500 elements in myrows. From the errors I think that I am running out of memory(?) but I haven't managed to find anything that would help me track down/diagnose this problem. Any ideas on how I would do this?

Answer (score 1):

can't you say something like below, if all you care is this second field?

`myrows=c.execute("select values.bust from values WHERE var=1")`

also, i am wondering you really want to create plot for each line...  dont you want to plot all the data in one plot?

Comment: Hi, Each entry in the database that I am selecting has its own data & its own plot that has to be made. The code I posted is a simplified version which just contains the steps (i.e. I have removed most of the variables). Cheers

Comment: so this make_plot() opens a file of ~8MB for every call and process that combining with a record in `myrows`?  Do you know error is coming from my_plot() or from this loop across records in your database?  Is there any chance that there is some memory leak in there or illegal access of memory?

Comment: It turned out that the version of the pyfits module that I was using (2.4) had a memory leak, I upgraded to 3.0 and it improved the problem, i.e. it ran for longer before using all my ram. 

It turns out that I was also missing a plt.close(fig) at the end of my plotting function - popped that it and it all worked fine.

Cheers

Comment: @user1027686: it is always great to hear that things start workin!

Answer (score 0):

Try and see if by changing your `for` statement to:

```
for burst in c.execute("select * from values WHERE var=1"):
    # your code here
```

rows aren't retrieved one at a time rather than in a single batch.